# CSV Import into a spreadsheet fails on QueryTables method

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need to import data from a CSV file.  I recorded the macro below but amended the "QueryTablesAdd" construct to concatnate the file location contained in the variable "FileLoc".  The macro works until it encounters the .Refresh BackgroundQuery := false method and fails at that point.
If I rem that method, the code actually runs through without failing.
Trouble is, it doesn't actually import the data.

Does anyone have any helpful hints?

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & FileLoc & Chr(34), Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "CDSTATS"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
   ' .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: why `Chr(34)`. Does your file name really have double quotes at the end of it?

Comment: Hi Scott - when I originally recorded the macro the entire Connection string was enclosed in double quotes.  Using Chr(34) was the only way I could replicate that structure and successfully concatenate the "FileLoc" variable.  It does actually succseefully open the relevant CSV file.

Comment: But you don't need the quotes when you are passing a variable, even a string variable. So, `"TEXT:myFile.csv"` = `"TEXT:" & myFile` when `myFile = "myFile.csv"` I know that may not solve your problem, but I just thought it was worth saying.

Comment: Hi Scott - you are absolutely right I had clearly got myself confused.  Not only was it well spotted, but it did also solve my problem.  Code now performing very well.  With my sincere thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer:

> you don't need the quotes when you are passing a variable, even a string variable

per @Scott Holtzman.